# Understanding a proof about the density of continuous points of a point-wise limit function.

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

This is an excerpt from a proof of a theorem.

> **Theorem 48.5** Suppose $X$ is a topological space and $(Y,d)$ is a metric space. Let $f_n:X\to Y$ be a series of continuous functions, and $f$ be its point-wise limit. If $X$ is a Baire space, there the points where $f$ is continuous are dense in $X$.

*Proof.* Given positive integer $N$ and $\epsilon > 0$, define
$$ A_N(\epsilon) = \{x|d(f_n(x), f_m(x))\le\epsilon \textrm{  for all  } n, m\ge N\}$$

Fix $\epsilon$, observe that $A_1(\epsilon)\subset A_2(\epsilon)\subset\cdots$. Now $X$ is the union of all of them. Observe that given $x_0\in X$, $x_0\in A_n(\epsilon)$ for a certain $N$.

Now, let
$$U(\epsilon)=\bigcup_{N\in\mathbb Z_+} \mathrm{Int}A_N(\epsilon)$$
We will show that

1. $U(\epsilon)$ is a dense open set in $X$
2. [...]

To show that $U(\epsilon)$ is a dense open set in $X$, we must show that given a nonempty open subset (denote $V$) of $X$, there exists an $V\cap \mathrm{Int}A_N(\epsilon) $ that is nonempty. For this, observe that for all $N$, $V\cap A_N(\epsilon) $ is closed. Because $V$ is an open subspace of $X$, $V$ is a Baire space. **So, there exists at least one set (denote $V\cap A_M(\epsilon) $) such that it contains a nonempty open subset of $V$.** (Call that open subset $W$.) Since $V$ is open in $X$, $W$ is open in $X$ as well. Therefore, it is included in $V\cap \mathrm{Int}A_M(\epsilon) $.

[...](proof of 2.)

---

I have difficulty understanding the highlighted line. It does not resemble to either the presumption or the conclusion of being a Baire space. How is it being deducted?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Sorry, I made a mistake copying (and translating) the text. I just edit the question to correct this part. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: 2nd question: Where did $V$ come from? It just appears without any definition.

Comment: @PaulSinclair It is a random open set.

Comment: Then why is it not introduced as such in the proof?

Comment: @PaulSinclair My mistake. I translated the text sentence by sentence, and missed something that is necessary to be read coherently in English. I just edit again.

Comment: Surely it should also be "$V\cap \mathrm{Int}A_N(\epsilon)$ is *open*", not "closed"? The intersection of two open sets will be open. It can only be closed as well for disconnected spaces. And I can see no reason this intersection should be closed. Though it still isn't clear what is going on in this argument. (By the way, "donate" means to give away, for example to a charity. I think the word you were after is "denote", which means "to write as".)

Comment: @PaulSinclair I feel bad about the abundant mistakes I have made (That was another one). Thanks a lot for your patience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106159/discussion-between-paul-sinclair-and-fantasie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the changes, I can figure it out, now.

- The $A_N(\epsilon)$ are closed by continuity of the metric $d$, functions $f_n$ and because the distance is allowed to take on $\epsilon$ as a value.
- Set $V_N := V \cap A_N(\epsilon)$. It is not correct to simply say $V_N$ is closed as you do in the proof. This is because "closed" by itself means as a subset of the ambient space $X$, and there is no reason this should be closed with respect to $X$. However, $V_N$ is closed *as a subset of $V$*.
- It was already noted that for any $x \in X, x \in A_N(\epsilon)$ for some $N$ (since $f_n(x)$ converges). So $\bigcup_N A_N(\epsilon) = X$, and also $\bigcup_N V_N = V$. In particular, the union has non-empty interior.
- If $\mathrm{Int}\ V_N = \emptyset$ for every $N$, then the $V_N$ would be closed nowhere-dense subsets of $V$, and therefore because $V$ is Baire, their union would have empty interior, which is false. Therefore, for at least one $M, \mathrm{Int}\ V_M$ is not empty.